# PHP performance tweak fgetcsv / array_filter

Tags: performance, fgetcsv

i'm

- reading a csv file using fgetcsv

  ```
  while (($data = (empty($this -> enclosure)) ? $method($fp, 10000, $this -> delimiter) : $method($fp, 10000, $this -> delimiter, $this -> enclosure)) !== FALSE)
  ```
- push every line to an array

  ```
              foreach($data as $l => $cont)
              {
                  $this -> line[$i][$this -> fieldlist[$l]] = $cont;
              }
  ```

  (while fieldlist is an array containing the header fields)
- query this array by using the header lines and array_filter

  ```
  public function csv_query($search_for = array())
  {
      $this -> timeset("start csv query");
      $return = array_filter($this -> line, function($var) use ($search_for){
      $trigger = 0;
      foreach($search_for as $index => $value)
      {
          if($var[$index] == $value)
          {
              $trigger+=1;
          }
      }

      return ($trigger == count($search_for)) ? true : false;
  });
  $this -> timeset("finished csv query");


  return $return;
  ```

  }

So far, so good... Does anyone knows how to tweak this method?

Of course iterating big arrays and fgetcsv take time. But here some measurements

```
1398418289.468287 - 0.000000 - initializing 
1398418289.468335 - 0.000048 - finished constructor 
1398418289.468410 - 0.000075 - file handler initialized 
1398418291.186548 - 1.718138 - finished fgetcsv 
1398418291.186563 - 0.000015 - start csv query 
1398418291.302163 - 0.115600 - finished csv query
```

- csv line count in this example: 19268
- the 'query array' was:

  $q = array(
      'VERFUEGBARKEIT' => 'JA',
      'HERSTELLERNUMMER'  =>  '906115301009'
  )

thx in advance

Comment: Try implementing the filter function in a static manner, not as a lambda function. Any difference?

Comment: 1398420150.617294 - 0.000016 - start csv query 
1398420150.728897 - 0.111603 - finished csv query

Comment: Um, sorry, didn't think before writing that comment. Obviously the problem is _before_ that issue...

Comment: np, it seems that fgetcsv is the real killer in that case. i'll try fopen instead and explode the lines manually.

Comment: ah $method = 'fgetcsv'

Comment: In special cases you might be able to speed things up that way. But not in a general way most likely. Parsing a csv file is non trivial, just thing of all the escaping. The c based implementation in php has an advantage there. But maybe, in case of really simply csv files you might be lucky.